# Ubuntu touch on Windows 8 (x86-64) tablet

Tags: windows-8, ubuntu-touch, tablet

A note to readers: Yes, this question has already been asked. However, most of the questions asked about this topic never received an answer, and those questions that did receive an answer are grossly outdated and don't apply to the current versions of Ubuntu Touch. Circumstances have changed, therefore, this question ***is NOT a duplicate***. Any off topic answers **will be flagged**.

I was reading up on the current Ubuntu daily builds yesterday, and I noticed that X86 support has officially been implemented into the current dev builds of Ubuntu touch.
[image]
This opens up a WHOLE bunch of new opportunities. I got to tinkering with an X86 emulator, using a modified Nexus 7 android bootloader in place of the traditional BIOS. I was able to get Ubuntu Touch running (slow as molasses, and not without the odd graphical issue), it was all going great, until U-T tried initializing the battery and the radio. It all crashed after that, even corrupted the image I was using to do it. However, this proves that Ubuntu Touch is capable of running on X86 hardware.

Now I'm pretty good with virtual hardware, but I suck when it comes to actually trying anything out on real hardware. I have no idea how to port an android bootloader to specific devices, much less attempting to manipulate Ubuntu touch into running on the disgraceful 32-bit UEFI firmware that comes with the majority of Windows (baytrail) tablets.

Honestly, getting an android bootloader to run in a virtual machine was bad enough, I had to create a virtual dynamic CPU that could switch between the ARM and x86 architecture inside of a running environment, without crashing, or even causing catastrophic damage to everything loaded in RAM.

So really, I just wanted to know if anyone had figured out how to get past these limitations, and in general, install Ubuntu Touch on a 32 or 64-bit Windows 8 tablet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Try to download the newest image from [Ubuntu Next](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-desktop-next/daily-live/current/). (This should be Unity8)
- Then download and add `bootia32.efi` to `.../EFI/boot/` on your install-USB-Stick to boot on that crappy 32-bit UEFI.

  This worked on my Pipo W1 Tablet, although touchscreen was not working and the wifi/blutooth driver also. Tried it on my desktop, worked but most apps crashed seconds after starting. :(

If it wont work with touch-ui (mir),

- try to:

  ```
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install unity8-lxc
  ```
- reboot and then

  ```
  sudo unity8-lxc-setup
  ```
- You can now choose the display manager at logging in. It runs in [LXC-Mode](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/lxc.html), so the rest of the system should not be destroyed if something goes wrong (i hope XD).

EDIT:
Also Touch is working on my Pipo W1, but i think it needs to be calibrated, i can not swipe in from the outside etc.

Comment: forgot that link: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity8inLXC

Comment: Thank you, my tablet is currently broken but I'm anxious to try out unity 8. I'll probably be using this method on my laptop for now.

Comment: @nubnade - Broken link to Ubuntu Next